# Concordance of an ordinal time series

Tags: time-series, concordance

I have panel data with an ordinal outcome that was assessed by two independent reviewers - i.e. each is unaware of the others' assessment. The time points for assessment are not necessarily concurrent, and the lengths of the series are not necessarily equal. Specifically, there are 4 possible levels where the 4th level, when observed, is the terminus of the series. We can assume the duration of scanning is frequent enough that interval censoring does not apply, that is that the state of the series can be carried forward until the next state is observed.

I would like to know what methods may be used to assess the concordance of these time series. Previously there was the concordance correlation coefficient of Lin that considers the orthogonal distance of observations from a concordance line for a continuous response. For these ordinal responses, I know that the "distance" between ordinal categories is too great to be considered continuous, but the specific value represents a range of possible continuous responses.

Comment: Are there enough time points such that you can fit a curves to interpolate?

Comment: Would Bayesian imputation of response at misaligned timepoints be useful?

Comment: Good thoughts @Galen . "Fitting curves" is a challenge, these "ordinal" categories are cancer responses. So you can go from stable disease (SD) to partial or complete response (PR, CR), but any reversal thereof immediately classifies you as progressive disease which is an absorbing state. SD->CR implies PR occurred "on the way" and is calculated based on the on-treatment nadir. So curves with 1:2:3:4 for PD SD PR CR are, in a sense, misleading. However, some patients may have up to 12 data points over 3 years so that the trend is coarsely understood. Other patients have only one assessment.

Comment: @Galen Bayesian imputation is a good thought. If we thought of the process as a Markov Model, then the only outstanding problem is expressing the transition probabilities with some kind of random effect for cluster characteristics. Are you suggesting that there would be methods for a continuous time process that could be applied here?

Comment: re ordered variables: Make sense. Taking a curve to interpolate in time while the image is discrete and ordered would require treating the problem as an [ordinal regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_regression).

Comment: re stochastic processes: Yes, using a continuous time stochastic process that achieves continuous partial pooling (e.g. Gaussian process) sounds promising. If you want to instead have discrete time, using a hierarchy of mixed effects representing the hierarchy of closeness in time sounds fine if you're fine with however many parameters that introduces.